# Calculate conditional cumulative sum with lag

Tags: r, dplyr, survival

I have this data frame:

```
have <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3),
                 tstart = c(0, 100, 200, 0, 0),
                 tstop = c(100, 200, 500, 400, 300),
                 tdc = c(0,1,1,0,1))
> have
  ID tstart tstop tdc
1  1      0   100   0
2  1    100   200   1
3  1    200   500   1
4  2      0   400   0
5  3      0   300   1
```

I would like to add a column with the cumulative sum of time from the interval tstart to tstop, conditional on tdc=1, i.e.,

```
want <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3),
                 tstart = c(0, 100, 200, 0, 0),
                 tstop = c(100, 200, 500, 400, 300),
                 tdc = c(0,1,1,0,1),
                 tdc.cum = c(0,100,400,0,300))
> want
  ID tstart tstop tdc tdc.cum
1  1      0   100   0       0
2  1    100   200   1     100
3  1    200   500   1     400
4  2      0   400   0       0
5  3      0   300   1     300
```

It would also be helpful to see how to lag the cumulative time by 10 units, i.e., subtract 10 units from each ID's total cumulative sum of rows with tdc=1.

```
want2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3),
                 tstart = c(0, 100, 200, 0, 0),
                 tstop = c(100, 200, 500, 400, 300),
                 tdc = c(0,1,1,0,1),
                 tdc.cum = c(0,100,390,0,290))
> want2
  ID tstart tstop tdc tdc.cum
1  1      0   100   0       0
2  1    100   200   1     100
3  1    200   500   1     390
4  2      0   400   0       0
5  3      0   300   1     290
```

I have tried to set up this data frame using survival::tmerge() and cumtdc() but I have only been able to get the cumulative sum of tdc (1 or 0) instead of the time interval. Thank you.

Comment: I meant to say earlier, your sample data are an exemplar of a [minimal reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for anyone wanting to know how. Every possible scenario in five rows, excellent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, this will achieve what you need. First, it calculates the cumulative sum of start/stop differences by group (ID). Second, if the last value in tdc for each group != 0, subtract 10 from last value in "tdc.cum":

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3),
                 tstart = c(0, 100, 200, 0, 0),
                 tstop = c(100, 200, 500, 400, 300),
                 tdc = c(0,1,1,0,1))

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(tdc.cum = cumsum(ifelse(tdc == 1, tstop - tstart, 0)),
         tdc.cum = ifelse(tdc.cum == max(tdc.cum) & tdc != 0, 
                          tdc.cum - 10, tdc.cum)) %>%
  ungroup()
         
# A tibble: 5 × 5
     ID tstart tstop   tdc tdc.cum
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1      0   100     0       0
2     1    100   200     1     100
3     1    200   500     1     390
4     2      0   400     0       0
5     3      0   300     1     290
```